# How I can draw image using bricks. Image can upload by uploader.

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am working on web application which have a bricks editor for draw sign using bricks. Till I can draw sign by char and number. Now I am try to draw image on bricks editor.

I want something like:

[upload this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EdoH.png)

[Draw this image like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XglKE.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution in javascript and  ajax handler.

Step 1. Draw the image on html control.

Step 2. Convert the image into base64 and pass to ajax handler

function GenerateImage()
{

```
    var imgElem = document.getElementById("uploadImg");                                                                                 // Get uploaded image name

    var tempcanvas = document.createElement("canvas");                                                                                  // Dynamic create canvas control
    tempcanvas.width = imgElem.clientWidth;
    tempcanvas.height = imgElem.clientHeight;
    var tempCtx = tempcanvas.getContext("2d");
    tempCtx.drawImage(imgElem, 0, 0);                                                                                                   // Draw image on canvas
    var dataURL = tempcanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    var imgData = dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");

    var parameter = "File64=" + imgData;                                                                                                // Set values in parameter
    var xmlhttp;        
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {                                                                                                        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {                                                                                                                              // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    if (xmlhttp) {
        xmlhttp.open("POST", "monoImageHandler.ashx", false);                                                                           // Call AJAX handler with post request                
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.send(parameter);                                                                                                        // Passes valuse as parameter 

        var imgColorXml;
        imgColorXml = xmlhttp.responseXML;                                                                                              // This is the code for getting the info of the client using text                           
        var totalRow = imgColorXml.getElementsByTagName("Color");
        var imgRowCount = parseInt(totalRow[0].getAttribute('RowNum'));
        setBackGroundUploadImage(imgElem.clientWidth, imgElem.clientHeight);                                                            // Set 

        // Draw x co-ordinate of rectangle
        for (var row = 0; row < imgRowCount; row++) {
            ctx.save();

            var y = imgColorXml.getElementsByTagName("Row_No" + row);
            var imgColCount = parseInt(y[0].getAttribute('ColNum'));

            // Draw y co-ordinate of rectangle
            for (var col = 0; col < imgColCount; col++) {

                var x = imgColorXml.getElementsByTagName("Row" + row);
                var colColor = x[col].getAttribute('Color');

                colColor = colColor.slice(2, 8);
                if (colColor != "ffffff")
                    ctx.fillStyle = "#" + colColor;
                else
                    ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFD0A";
                ctx.save();
                ctx.translate(col * WIDTH, row * HEIGHT);
                drawImageBrick();
                ctx.restore();
            }
            ctx.restore();
        }
    }
}

// Draw bricks and manage gaphs between bricks
function drawImageBrick() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(1, 1, WIDTH - WMargin, HEIGHT - HMargin);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
}
```

Read image colors pixel by pixel on ajax handler.

Step 3. Temporary draw the image on server end using base64.

Step 4. Read the image colors pixel by pixel and store into dynamic XML.

step 5. Return this xml and read colors and draw on bricks.

```
/// This function read saved image from server

/// Convert it into bitmap data and read pixel by pixel color
```

private string ReadJpeg(string ImgName)
{

XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();

XmlElement root = xml.CreateElement("Color");                                                                               // Root node
        xml.AppendChild(root);

```
    XmlComment comment = xml.CreateComment("Image Color");
    root.AppendChild(comment);

    var path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("Images");                                                                    // Get server path for pick saved image
    var imgBitData = new Bitmap(path + "/" + ImgName);

    var imgWidth = imgBitData.Width;
    var imgHeight = imgBitData.Height;

    root.SetAttribute("RowNum", imgHeight.ToString());

    for (int i = 0; i < imgHeight; i++)
    {
        XmlElement Row_No = xml.CreateElement("Row_No" + i);
        Row_No.SetAttribute("ColNum", imgWidth.ToString());
        for (int j = 0; j < imgWidth; j++)
        {
            // Read the color from pallete
            Color pixelColor = imgBitData.GetPixel(j, i);                                                                       // Get pixel by pixel color of image
            XmlElement Row = xml.CreateElement("Row" + i);
            Row.SetAttribute("Color", pixelColor.Name.ToString());
            Row_No.AppendChild(Row);            
        }
        root.AppendChild(Row_No);
    }
    imgBitData.Dispose();                                                                                                       // Free image resource
    FileInfo myfileinf = new FileInfo(path + "/" + ImgName);                                                                    // Delete image after complete process
    myfileinf.Delete();
    GC.Collect();          
    return xml.OuterXml;
}
```

[image: Upload this image]

[image: Output of uploaded image]